# Cannot compile Tomcat Native Library on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, tomcat, openssl

**Background -**

I'm using Tomcat 9.0.8 as webserver for an Oracle APEX installation. I now need to make Tomcat FIPS-140 compliant. To this end, I'm trying to build the Tomcat Native Library, incorporating a FIPS-compliant OpenSSL. I've been working from these instructions:

https://www.ysofters.com/2017/07/25/building-and-using-fips-capable-openssl-in-apache-tomcat/

There are "official" Tomcat Native build instructions from Apache, but they require the use of Mladen's Custom Microsoft Compiler Toolkit Compilation, which AFAIK can't be built on Windows 10.

The build steps were as follows:

- Build the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module
- Build the FIPS capable OpenSSL
- Build Apache Portable Runtime
- Build Tomcat Native library

The last step is what failed, hence my question today.

**Build Configuration -**

Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)
Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.6

**Build Errors -**

According to the build docs, I needed to run the following nmake command:

```
nmake -f NMAKEMakefile WITH_APR=E:\native_build\deps\apr WITH_OPENSSL=E:\native_build\deps\openssl APR_DECLARE_STATIC=1 ENABLE_OCSP=1 WITH_FIPS=1
```

E:\native_build\deps contains compiled versions of Apache Portable Runtime and OpenSSL, built in the previous steps.

That nmake command results in these errors:

```
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapi.h(1105): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'FileInformationClass'
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapi.h(1105): error C2081: 'FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS': name in formal parameter list illegal
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapi.h(1105): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FileInformationClass'
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapi.h(1105): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapi.h(1105): error C2059: syntax error: ','
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\fileapi.h(1108): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9118): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'FileInformationClass'
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9118): error C2081: 'FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS': name in formal parameter list illegal
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9118): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FileInformationClass'
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9118): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9118): error C2059: syntax error: ','
E:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\winbase.h(9121): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
```

I haven't been able to locate a solution to this, or even another instance of the problem, so hoping you folks have some insights.